Pynput Listening Then Controlling Keyboard to Type Causing It to Type Twice
The following code waits for a global F1 key press, then controls the keyboard to type out the string "hello".
from pynput import keyboard

print("Waiting for key press...")

with keyboard.Events() as events:
    for event in events:
        if event.key == keyboard.Key.f1:
            print("1")
            break
    print("2")

print("Received key press.")

print("Simulating key press...")

controller = keyboard.Controller()
controller.type("hello")

print("Finished key press.")

But as the result, the word that got typed out is:
helloello

instead of
hello

The console log is normal:
Waiting for key press...
1
2
Received key press.
Simulating key press...
Finished key press.

Without the listening part, it works normally.
I have tried listening to different keys, such as F3, HOME, DOWN and SPACE and in different applications, such as code editor and Notes.app, but it is still not working, and the string helloello was typed out. I am running Mac OS Sonoma 14.5 and Python 3.12.3.
